# Answering the Diversity Question for Mathematics Instructor Applications

Tags: interviewing, applications, cover-letter, education

As I apply for several other colleges who are hiring part time math teachers, I find myself wondering about this question as it is asked on ALL college instruction applications. Some of the questions that have came about in the adjunct faculty math applications are:

1. Describe your experience working with diverse socio-economic students
2. Ability and willingness to work with students from a wide range of socioeconomic backgrounds.
3. Ability to motivate and teach studnets with diverse cultural, socio-economic and ethnic backgrounds, preparation, learning styles, and disabilities, using instructional methods that reflect cultural sensitivity and interdisciplinary approaches to subject matter.
   Incorporating materials and activities that reflect the role of mathematics in students’ lives.

My question is, how do you formulate an answer to such a question?

Comment: I would drop the quotation at the beginning, `I have had the privilege of working with students...` sounds like a good intro to me and you seem to cover all the points

Comment: @Brandin thank you. Any particular reason why?

Comment: Try dropping the quote and reread your paragraph. I think your first sentence without the quote is a stronger opening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will answer this question most effectively, if you ask your self why they asked that question in the first place?

1. As the first one in my family to go to university and from my experience of having tutored and taught some of these students at Columbia University's Program Double Discovery, I can tell you that their problem runs much deeper than a mere lack of money.
2. It's a fact that middle class students do better in American schools than say Black or Hispanic students from a disadvantaged background. American schools are geared to meet the needs of middle class kids,or kids whose attitudes mirror middle class values. The same school that does brilliantly by these middle class kids may fail just as poorly with these kids from a disadvantaged background.
3. A big part of the problem is that middle class teachers don't have a clue how to reach kids from a disadvantaged background. It's not the fault of the middle class teachers that they were raised the way they were. The fact is, there is no Top Gun program anywhere in the country that teaches you or anyone else how to teach these kids efficiently. In fact, the lack of institutional support for those teachers who have to teach these kids borders on criminal negligence.
4. A lot of ordinary citizens live under the misconception that all it takes to be a good teacher is being a Subject Matter Expert (SME). However, teaching is much more than teaching the subject. You're teaching students - people, not just the subject. If you are a failure at teaching people,it doesn't matter how knowledgeable about the subject you are.
5. A teacher who might be rated as a star middle class, suburban school district - that teacher might not last five minutes with these students from a disadvantaged background. I was the first one in my family to to University,my family was at times as poor as theirs and it featured a single head of household. But I'll be the first to tell you that my kind of disadvantaged background was nowhere like theirs. The kind of teachers that succeed with these students might be poorly rated elsewhere for say,lack of subject matter expertise. It's a tough, complex, miserable situation.

The reason they ask you that question is bitter experience with students from this disadvantaged background. They want to see that you are not just some starry eyed idealist who will fall apart in a minority urban setting, and whom they expect to fail because they will be providing you with little to no institutional support in reaching out to these students and teaching them effectively.

You need to make the following points in answering the question:
"

1. Yeah, I have taught some of these kids. Nobody taught me how to teach these kids and I had to learn to teach these kids the same way everybody else did and who is still teaching the kids - the hard way.
2. I have been exposed to some of the challenges of these kids,I've been successful in reaching out to these kids and teaching them, but it was no picnic, and from my own experience, I can see why so many teachers fail.
3. I love these kids and teaching these kids, despite these challenges that I am all too aware of.
   "

I regret to say that Your statement that "mathematics is the great equalizer" is as trite as the statement that "knowledge is the great equalizer". It has the same value to me as the statement "You and I will be together for the rest of our lives,because we love each other and love conquers all".

Love did conquer all in the case of Romeo and Juliet and they were together for the rest of their lives, but their lifespan was kind of brutally short - We're talking days, here :)

Comment: +1, excellent answer!  I am also from a disadvantaged background and have been involved in outreach and teaching.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable advice this really is an eye opener for me. I'll have to adjust my answer. Thank you.

Comment: For about 6 years I've been working with students from low income communities. I have been exposed to some of the challenges of these students, I've been successful in reaching out to these students and teaching them by providing extended office hours, extended due date times on homework assignments - especially for working parents, examination retakes to improve their grades, accommodations for disabled students (preferential seating, visual aids, guided notes, graphic organizers), and typed/printed notes for students who are absent and have to miss class as a resultof overtime fromtheir jobs

Comment: ^^A little better?

Comment: @ProfessorMadrigal Be specific about the challenges you have faced - students who read at three grade levels below what they are supposed to be, students whose families are on the verge of homelessness, students who are disruptive, students who don't give a damn and whose parents don't give a damn. You are doing a good job detailing your specific activities but I'd like to know some of the ways you have reached out to these students and motivated them not merely to park their butts in your class but to actually study in it. In terms of style, don't write sentences longer than 1.5 to 2 lines.

Comment: @ProfessorMadrigal You don't have to disclose what you did to motivate these students in your cover letter but you have to be prepared to discuss the matter at your interviews. Because they're sure to ask you about it - Don't worry that you never found a silver bullet for these issues. Because if there were one, it would be in my possession and everybody would be begging me for it :)

Comment: How can I answer such a complex question in 2 lines?

Comment: @ProfessorMadrigal I mean, you should ansswer such a complex question in a series of sentences, where each sentence is no longer than 2 lines each. Sentences that are longer than 2 lines are hard to read and usually pretty hard to write :)

Comment: Ways I have reached out students and motivated them are 1) Establishing rapport with them via student survey (with comments on their responses) and making them feel 'at home' sort to speak by providing them with information of their aspiring careers in relation to the course (i have way more examples) 2) Creating Novelty - using maps, videos, stories, that help them connect math with real life rather than a bland abstract course that just focuses on theorems and examples 3) Easily approachable - I make myself accessible at all times through emails, appointments, etc.

Comment: ^^ just some stuff that came up on top of my head

Comment: @ProfessorMadrigal Excellent :) What took you so long? :) I'll note that making yourself available is only the beginning of the story - what's important is that you made the extra effort to be there for them :) What's amazing is that you did it without burning yourself out in the process - If you can do this without burning out, then you are one of the few :)

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan lol I needed a great advisor to bring it out of me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Context: I used to be an instructor, in a different but related field.]

It's not that there's anything wrong with what you've said, but it really doesn't address the question.

Put yourself in the position of people hiring for instructors.  They are thinking (or *should be* thinking!) along the lines of

"We have a very varied bunch of students here: different backgrounds, different ethnicities and cultures, different language skills, some students with impairments (physical, learning), some students who are poor, some who study part-time, some who have carer responsibilities, etc. We have a (legal and) moral duty to make sure all of these students can learn in a supportive environment and have an enjoyable learning experience, and we want to hire instructors who have experience with such diversity and can facilitate that."

In summary, your statement says "Mathematics is diverse" and you've given a laundry list of different types of people who have been in your classes. If I was such a person doing some hiring, that statement would not reassure me.

Instead - think! How did you deal with such diversity? What specific measures have you taken in the past to help students who are atypical?  Some good examples would really help here, and give the people doing the hiring an impression that you don't just *say* that you support diversity, but that you actually *do support* diversity.

If you truly do support diversity and do carry this support into your teaching, then you should have examples you could talk about, in proportion to how much experience you've had.  Personally, I have a whole bunch of examples from my teaching experience, e.g. what specific steps I took for that deaf student and how that improved my teaching subsequently; the particular disability accommodations I made for that test and how I knew they were working ok; what measures I took for people for whom English was not their first language; how I chose illustrative examples bearing in mind cultural sensitivities; accessibility guidelines I used for instructional materials; etc etc etc.

If you don't have such examples, then I suggest that you improve your teaching style to better take into accounts the diverse needs of the student body. You could also start thinking about the issue and thinking about what sorts of approaches you *should* be taking, even if you haven't in the past.

Comment: Here's what I have from top of my head:

Comment: Forabout 6 years I've been working with students from low income communities. I have been exposed to some of the challenges of these students, I've been successful in reaching out to these students and teaching them by providing extended office hours, extended due date times on homework assignments - especially for working parents, examination retakes to improve their grades, accommodations for disabled students (preferential seating, visual aids, guided notes, graphic organizers), and typed/printed notes for students who are absent and have to miss class as a resultof overtime fromtheir jobs

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself: why are the colleges asking this question? The answer is likely because they and their granting agencies both have a strong commitment to educating people from all sorts of cultural backgrounds, and they need to make sure their adjuncts share this commitment.

What you've written is your personal reflection on diversity and it is excellent. But with respect it may be too long and dense for a job application.

Can you, based on the core values in your statement, give a one-sentence answer to each of the numbered questions?

Also, skip the "math is a great equalizer" stuff, if only because the dean reading your application may be a chemist. This college just wants you to help would-be nurses and business people learn the math they need to understand and enjoy the rest of their coursework. Futbol is a great equalizer too.

Comment: Forabout 6 years I've been working with students from low income communities. I have been exposed to some of the challenges of these students, I've been successful in reaching out to these students and teaching them by providing extended office hours, extended due date times on homework assignments - especially for working parents, examination retakes to improve their grades, accommodations for disabled students (preferential seating, visual aids, guided notes, graphic organizers), and typed/printed notes for students who are absent and have to miss class as a resultof overtime fromtheir jobs

Comment: ^^ A little better? Just a rough response which of course I will be editing. But is that answering it more directly?

Comment: Looks, to me, very good indeed. You might consider mentioning something about challenging students to take responsibility for their own learning while helping them get past various cultural obstacles.

Comment: That's definitely true I MUST put that somewhere because I sound as if I'm making it sound like 80/20 teacher to student proposition